# Uninstall CandyCrushCrap and keep it off

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I know we have a reg key that is supposed to keep Microsoft from installing CandyCrush@%#$ and what have you at major Windows updates,

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsStore\WindowsUpdate\AutoDownload
```

But is there a way to uninstall them on already polluted machines?
I can use

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.OneNote | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.OneNote | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage
```

to uninstall "normal" apps, like OneNote. And I found `this` reference from Microsoft about making sure things STAY Deprovisioned. And I have found some references to using the PackageFullName to deal with this junk. But 
`Remove-AppxPackage king.com.BubbleWitch3Saga_3.5.8.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32` runs and claims success, while not actually deleting anything. And `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage king.com.BubbleWitch3Saga_3.5.8.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32` throws an error. And using Get-AppxPackage does nothing. It's so offensive that Microsoft will pollute "professionalismsl" OS's with this junk.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this for all users (and references) with PowerShell. The AppxPackage-CMD'lets provide a `-AllUsers` Option for that and can also match jokers (?*) so that you don't have to provide the right version numbers.

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *candy* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

I am using this Scripts at the moment:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *3dbuilder* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Asphalt* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *windowsphone* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *CandyCrush* | Remove-AppxPackag
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *DrawboardPDF* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *getstarted* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *Facebook* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *feedback* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *zunevideo* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *bingfinance* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *zunemusic* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *people* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *bingnews* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *messaging* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *officehub* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *onenote* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *mspaint* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *skypeapp* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *bingsports* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *dvd* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *xboxIdentityprovider* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *xboxapp* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

Comment: what build are you doing this on? I just did a cut & paste on a Windows 10 Pro 1703 VM, and no errors, but Candy Crush Soda Saga is still there, making Microsoft look like pathetic shills for crapware.

Comment: Then it (maybe) does not match correctly. Currently I am on 1909, but I am using this since 2017.

Comment: I ran your script and got nothing but The operation completed, but errors were encountered. 
For additional information, look in Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeployment/Operational in the Event Log. The actual event log has nothing useful either.